# Pick out true statements

Tags: real-analysis

Pick out true statements

1.Any continuous function on $[0,1]$ is of bounded variation

2.If $f$ is continuously differentiable  on $\mathbb R$the restriction of $f$ on $[-1,1]$ is of bounded variation

3.Any monotone function is of bounded variation.

I am able to show 3 is true; for 1 I have the following counter example but not sure about the other one

$f(x)=xsin\frac{1}{x}  ;x\neq0 
$

$f(0)=0$

Comment: On a purely logical argument, if all continuous functions were BV, then we would not need a name for BV functions. Think of $ f(x)=sin(1/x), x\neq 0, f(0)=0$. For 2, yes, continuous on compact is uniformly continuous.

Comment: You do not need that "continuous on compact is uniformly continuous". Still, a continuously differentiable function on a compact interval is even absolutely continuous an in particular of bounded variation.

Comment: @PassingBy: Even if all continuous functions are of BV, there are still noncontinuous functions of BV. Also, your example $f$ is not continuous on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @PhoemueX: I never claimed it was necessary, only that it is sufficient.

Comment: @John: Sorry, I just meant that uniformly continuous functions are BV, and I misread your claim, sorry. And, yes, I missed the term x in xsin(1/x) , my bad.